# PHP Variable in a string in a string

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am attempting to echo a sting containing a variable already stored in a variable. Essentially I am building a class that can dynamically build tables based on a changing number of columns. I need get my db field names into the foreach loop before the foreach loop that has my db results, and then iterate over them in the loop. The problem is I have to store them in a loop prior to the db results loop; which is not recognizing it as a variable and just giving me a plain text '$row['myVar']'.

How can I get this to recognize the variable in the second loop?

```
$sqlVarNames = explode(', ', $sqlVar);
foreach ($sqlVarNames as $columnVar) {
    $finalColumnVars .= '<td>\'. $row[\''.$columnVar.'\'] .\'</td>';
}
```

and then into my second loop

```
foreach ($sqlResult as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo $finalColumnVars;
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I tried all sorts of escape sequences on my $finalColumnVars and can't seem to get it to output the variable instead on plain text.

Here is what I get with the above code

```
<td>'. $row['client_name'] .'</td>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: try this `'<td>'. $row[$columnVar] .'</td>'`

Comment: This returns '<td></td>'. I'm guessing because $row isn't anything in the first loop.

Comment: seems like you want to parse/execute/substitute php code from a string. perhaps some string substitution can help you here.

Comment: `'<td>'. $columnVar.'</td>'` will be ok here. Because $row is defined nowhere.

Comment: $columnVar is the db field name that needs to go in $row['$columnVar']. '<td>'. $columnVar.'</td>' would just output the field name and not it's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can merge these two loop and get the desired.

```
$sqlVarNames = explode(', ', $sqlVar);
foreach ($sqlResult as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($sqlVarNames as $columnVar) {
        echo '<td>'. $row[$columnVar] .'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$sqlVarNames = explode(', ', $sqlVar);
foreach ($sqlVarNames as $columnVar) {
    $finalColumnVars .= '<td>'.$row[$columnVar].'</td>';
}
```

Comment: This returns '<td></td>'. I'm guessing because $row isn't anything in the first loop.

Comment: Ya you have to wrap the one `foreach` inside the other `foreach`